# Android app export with Pro guard giving errors

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I am just done with a small android app in which i need to use pro-guard for obfuscating any private keys. I have enabled pro-guard in project (IDE Eclipse) but while exporting, its giving me following errors (just pasting few of them):

```
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't      find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer. Transferable
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyEditor
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyEditor
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.MappingStrategy: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - ABC] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - Remembrall] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - Remembrall]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - Remembrall] Warning: there were 286 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - Remembrall]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-09-13 15:12:05 - Remembrall] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-09-13 15:12:06 - Remembrall] WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list.
[2014-09-13 15:12:06 - Remembrall] Because v13 includes v4, using only v13.
[2014-09-13 15:12:07 - Remembrall] WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list.
[2014-09-13 15:12:07 - Remembrall] Because v13 includes v4, using only v13.
[2014-09-13 15:12:18 - Remembrall] WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list.
[2014-09-13 15:12:18 - Remembrall] Because v13 includes v4, using only v13.
[2014-09-13 15:12:18 - Remembrall] WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list.
[2014-09-13 15:12:18 - Remembrall] Because v13 includes v4, using only v13.
```

Comment: SO please let me know how to solve this, its like i am missing some configration part of pro-guard.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to proguard config file (proguard-android.txt)

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-keep class javax.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.** {*;}
-keep public class Mail {*;}        
-dontshrink
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the OpenCSV library, but it looks like it was designed for standard Java. Android Java is the same programming language, but not the same runtime environment. I see references to `java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable` and `java.beans.PropertyEditor` in your error message. These classes don't exist on Android ([full package list here](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)). No amount of Proguard config is going to add them. You'll have to use a different CSV processing library, or at least, strip out and work around the parts of OpenCSV you can't use.